# Other customers address show on checkout - security bug in magento

Tags: checkout, session, security, cookie, customer-address

**We have an issue with magento checkout -**

A customer logged into his account and in checkout page wrong address is shown and the interesting fact is that it is some other customer's address. The same address appears in order mail also.

The same thing happened for some other customers also.

Our customer just called and said that the problem appeared again and he is afraid that his data is not being handled safely.

I think it is some issue with session handling.

Additional Information

1. Magento version : 1.4.2.0
2. Checkout : Idev onepagecheckout
3. Stores : 2 websites for 2 languages

This issue needs to be fixed asap. Please help me.

Comment: I think this issue is connected with this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911204/magento-users-can-see-others-data

Comment: What are the Session Validation sessions that you are using (System=>Configuration=>Web)? And do you use a Full Page Cache extension?

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff
Session Validation Settings 
---------------------
Validate REMOTE_ADDR - No, 
Validate HTTP_VIA - No,
Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR - No,
Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT - No,
Use SID on Frontend - Yes
------------
We are not using Full Page Cache extension.
Magento Community Edition - 1.4.2.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you made any progress? We're using CE Version 1.8.1.0   My web host is Cloudways. I have the same Configuration=>Web settings.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned by Vladimir in the comments: This can happen due to **session collision** and/or i**nsufficient caching mechanisms**.

Chances for session collision are higher, the longer you keep your customer sessions and the longer the cookie lifetime is.

Caching blocks with customer specific information can lead to the same issues.